# Using ember.js with yesod

Tags: javascript, haskell, web, ember.js, yesod

As seen on http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/ ember templates system requires to generate pseudo-html which looks like :

```
<div id="logo">
  <img {{bind-attr src=logoUrl}} alt="Logo">
</div>
```

But I can't find a way to makes Hamlet compliant with this kind of non standard output.
Do I need to escape everything when ember's elements binding is needed or is their another solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used ember.js, but I believe you'll need to do some kind of escaping. I believe your example could be expressed in Hamlet as:

```
<div #logo>
    \<img {{bind-attr src=logoUrl}} alt="Logo">
```

Comment: If everything is that easy to escape then I'm good with that. Thanks.